# Prevent using specific annotation in project classes on compile time or at runtime

Tags: java, compilation, annotations

I have to prevent using specific annotations in my project. Due to some specific circumstances, I have to prevent using `org.junit.After` annotation in project test classes. If anyone uses this annotation, whole tests logic will be violated.

It doesn't matter for me if it will happen during compilation or at runtime. My idea was to create aspect using Spring AOP which throws an exception on call `After` annotated method. Unfortunately, test classes are not Spring beans so AOP will not work here.

How can I do that? Is it possible to put some compilator directives which will prohibit using specific annotation?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @lexicore It's because same problem as [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/115). I'm using selenium and I have to do screenshots on failed tests, but before 'After' logic. Following official JUnit statement and advice, I moved 'After' logic to different rule which call 'tearDown' method from base class. That's why I need to force users to override 'tearDown' method from base class instead of creating their own one with `@After` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an `AnnotationProcessor` to generate error in complie period

Here is the annotation processor ([find code on github](https://github.com/XDean/StackOverflow/blob/master/src/main/java/xdean/stackoverflow/java/annotation/Q49706464.java)):

```
@AutoService(Processor.class)
@SupportedAnnotation(After.class)
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class Q49706464 extends XAbstractProcessor {
  @Override
  public boolean processActual(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) throws AssertException {
    roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(After.class)
        .forEach(e -> error().log("@After is banned.", e));
    return false;
  }
}
```

For the following java file

import org.junit.After;

```
public class ForQ49706464 {
  @After
  public void after() {

  }
}
```

You will get following compile error

```
ForQ49706464.java:7: error: @After is banned.
  public void after() {
              ^
```

And you can integrate the annotation processor in your IDE to see the error message in text editor directly.

*The `XAbstractProcessor` is from my library [`Annotation Processor Toolkit`](https://github.com/XDean/AnnotationProcessorToolkit)*